# Method in Java showing error in Eclipse, builds fine with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-8

I cant get rid of this error in Eclipse.  The project is using Java 8 and so is Eclipse so I am at a stand still why I am getting this error below.

```
The method setTomcatContextCustomizers(Collection<? extends TomcatContextCustomizer>) in the type TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory is not applicable for the arguments (List<Object>)

 tomcatFactory.setTomcatContextCustomizers(Arrays.asList(context -> {
                    JDBCStore store = new JDBCStore();
                    store.setDriverName(tomcatConfig.getStoreDriverName());
                    store.setConnectionURL(jdbcUrl);
                    store.setConnectionName(jdbcUser);
                    store.setConnectionPassword(jdbcPassword);
                    store.setSessionAppCol(tomcatConfig.getStoreSessionAppCol());
                    store.setSessionDataCol(tomcatConfig.getStoreSessionDataCol());
                    store.setSessionIdCol(tomcatConfig.getStoreSessionIdCol());
                    store.setSessionLastAccessedCol(tomcatConfig.getStoreSessionLastAccessedCol());
                    store.setSessionMaxInactiveCol(tomcatConfig.getStoreSessionMaxInactiveCol());
                    store.setSessionTable(tomcatConfig.getStoreSessionTable());
                    store.setSessionValidCol(tomcatConfig.getStoreSessionValidCol());
                    PersistentManager pm = new PersistentManager();
                    pm.setDistributable(true);
                    pm.setProcessExpiresFrequency(tomcatConfig.getPersistenceManagerProcessExpiresFrequency());
                    pm.setMaxIdleBackup(tomcatConfig.getPersistenceManagerMaxIdleBackup());
                    pm.setStore(store);
                    context.setManager(pm);
                }));
```

Comment: Which version of Eclipse? With what project settings? Using what JRE library?

Comment: I guess, it’s because Eclipse’s Java 8 support will need some years to catch up with `javac` (and even `javac` is far away from being stable and bug free…).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried cleaning up your eclipse workspace by going to Project->Clean and then refreshing it by going to File->Refresh?

This usually works for me when I encounter the same behavior with errors showing up in eclipse but not while building with maven.

Answer (score 0):

Adding and activating an external Maven installation via Eclipse's menu Window → Preferences → Maven → Installations always helped me when this happened to me with Eclipse Kepler and Java 7.